# Who is the girl in the movie Southbound?

Tags: plot-explanation, southbound

In the movie Southbound (2015), Mitch and Jack do this at the end:

They kill a husband and wife. They also show the husband a photo of a girl when they stab him.

Who is this girl?

Why are Mitch and Jack murdering a seemingly normal family for the sake of the girl in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

The girl is Mitch's daughter Katherine that Daryl (the dad) had murdered.  This is why they whisper "eye for an eye" to them while they kill Daryl and his wife.  The masked intruders were seeking vengeance for Katherine's murder.  Mitch also whispers what Daryl had done to Katherine in Daryl's wife's ear before he kills her.

Katherine also appears in the segment earlier in the film where Daryl is stuck in the time loop in "[The Way Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southbound_(2015_film)#The_Way_Out)."  Where Daryl is trapped in the hallway of the house  with the torment that he was not able to save his daughter.

Comment: thanks @followthemeow. What I was confused about was the reaction the wife gives. There is a moment she realizes what it is all about when the husband starts to say "sorry". It's like she knows something but not the full details. Doesn't seem to be a murder that she knows about ..